# Calculate mean for each unique value in column and insert into the column where it equals 0 in R

Tags: r, dplyr, data-manipulation

Data for my example.

```
date1 = seq(as.Date("2019/01/01"), by = "month", length.out = 48)
date2 = seq(as.Date("2019/02/01"), by = "month", length.out = 48)
date3 = seq(as.Date("2019/02/01"), by = "month", length.out = 48)
date4 = seq(as.Date("2019/02/01"), by = "month", length.out = 48)
date = c(date1,date2,date3,date4)



subproducts1=rep("1",48)
subproducts2=rep("2",48)
subproductsx=rep("x",48)
subproductsy=rep("y",48)

b1 <- c(rnorm(48,5))
b2 <- c(rnorm(48,5))
b3 <-c(rnorm(48,5) )
b4 <- c(rnorm(48,5))

dfone <- data.frame(
                "date"= date,
               
                "subproduct"= 
                  c(subproducts1,subproducts2,subproductsx,subproductsy),
                "actuals"= c(b1,b2,b3,b4))
```

This creates Jan 2019 for date2,3,4 with value 0.

```
 dfone <-dfone %>%
 complete(date = seq.Date(from = min(date), to = as.Date('2021-06-01'), by = 'month'), 
       nesting(subproduct), fill = list(actuals = 0))
```

QUESTION: How can I calculate the mean value for each unique subproduct (4 in this case) and insert the mean into each respective Jan 2019 that was created with value = 0? I know I can do this manually, but is there any function that does this easily?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could do a group by replace i.e. grouped by 'subproduct', create the condition in `replace` where 'actuals' values are 0, then update those with `mean` of 'actuals' without including the 0 values in `mutate`

```
library(dplyr)
dfone_new <- dfone %>%
      group_by(subproduct)  %>%
      mutate(actuals = replace(actuals, actuals == 0, 
          mean(actuals[actuals != 0], na.rm = TRUE))) %>%
      ungroup
```

---

Or in the `complete`, if we didn't change it to 0, it is more direct with `na.aggregate` from `zoo` which by default uses function `mean` to replace the `NA` elements

```
library(tidyr)
library(zoo)
dfone_new <- dfone %>%
    complete(date = seq.Date(from = min(date), 
       to = as.Date('2021-06-01'), by = 'month'), 
         nesting(subproduct)) %>%
     group_by(subproduct) %>%
     mutate(actuals = na.aggregate(actuals)) %>%
     ungroup
```

-output

```
dfone_new
# A tibble: 195 x 3
   date       subproduct actuals
   <date>     <chr>        <dbl>
 1 2019-01-01 1             5.67
 2 2019-01-01 2             5.01
 3 2019-01-01 x             5.00
 4 2019-01-01 y             4.98
 5 2019-02-01 1             3.97
 6 2019-02-01 2             5.42
 7 2019-02-01 x             5.09
 8 2019-02-01 y             3.98
 9 2019-03-01 1             5.18
10 2019-03-01 2             5.08
# … with 185 more rows
```

Comment: Hey, to add onto this. How can I make it so the mean is limited only up to max Date of Dec 2020 for example and not the whole data for each product/subproduct?

Comment: Did you get a chance to look at the new question I posted

Comment: @chriswang123456 I posted the solution there and then deleted as you didn't respond back

Comment: Ah I'm sorry I got caught up with some things. If you want to post it again I'll upvote your answer, if not it's okay

Comment: @chriswang123456 i undeleted.  I was thinking that it was not the answer you wanted.

Comment: Sorry. I always will respond if I see it. Thanks again.